# Search using Combo Box and Filter the results in text boxes

Tags: vb6

I am trying to do a small program on VB 6.0 to find the records in database and print it in text box based on combo box selection but i failed to find a code which allow me to do this.

Any help please.

```
Dim adoCon
Dim adoRs
Dim strSQL As String


Dim strDB As String

'Change YourDatabaseName to actual database you have
strDB = "c:\path\YourDatabaseName.accdb"



Set adoCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
adoCon.Open "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " & _
"Data Source = " & strDB & ";" & _
"Persist Security Info = False;"

'Change Table1 to your table name in MS Access
'change the name of combobox and the fieldname in MS Access table
'
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''' ''''''''''''''''''''''
' if combo is numeric 
strSQL = "SELECT [fieldNameToReturn] FROM Table1 Where [fieldName] = " + [combo].Value + ";"

' if combo is text
'strSQL = "SELECT [fieldNameToReturn] FROM Table1 Where [fieldName] = '" + [combo].Value + "';"
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''' '''''''''''''''''''''''

Set adoRs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

'Set the cursor type we are using so we can navigate through the recordset
adoRs.CursorType = 2

'Set the lock type so that the record is locked by ADO when it is updated
adoRs.LockType = 3

'Open the tblComments table using the SQL query held in the strSQL varaiable
'adoRs.Open strSQL, adoCon

If Not adoRS.Eof() Then
[yourTextBox] = adoRs(0)
End If 
adoRs.Close
adoCon.Close
Set adoRs = Nothing
Set adoCon = Nothing
```

Comment: I think in Vb6 we use "&" instead of "+" for string concatenation....

Comment: VB.NET is not the same thing as VB6

Comment: Probably you should uncomment the line that opens recordset and use your object and control names where indicated.

Comment: Both & and + will concatenate strings but different things happen if encounter Null or only numeric values.

Comment: Could you please amend the code and provide me with a final one

Comment: How should anyone amend your code? We don't know your object and field names nor your database path. Do the edits as suggested and see what happens when you run the code. Then edit your question with new info.

Comment: [FieldNameToReturn]? Table1? [Combo] .Value?
This code is not 'real'. Show us what you really use and indicate what error you receive.

Answer (score 0):

"BOF" below is not a typo. If the recordset is empty (the query returned no records) BOF will be true.

```
adoRs.Open strSQL, adoCon
If Not adoRS.BOF Then
    'If not _BOF_ we have records so load the first record
    adoRs.MoveFirst

    'If first field is a string then use this
    [yourTextBox] = adoRs.Fields(0).Value

    'If first field is numeric then use this
    [yourTextBox] = CStr(adoRs.Fields(0).Value)
Else
    Msgbox "No records returned."
End If
```

If you were processing multiple records you would still do the MoveFirst and then loop until EOF was true, processing each record. The MoveNext will set EOF = True when there are no more records to process.

```
adoRs.Open strSQL, adoCon
If Not adoRS.BOF Then
    'If not _BOF_ we have records so load the first record
    adoRs.MoveFirst

    Do While Not adoRS.EOF 
        'Process records here
        '.
        '.
        '.
        adoRS.MoveNext
    Loop
Else
    Msgbox "No records returned."
End If
```

Comment: its returned an error "Arguments are of the wrong type are out of acceptable range or are in conflict with one another " on adoRs.Open strSQL, adoCon line , could you please help .

Comment: This is VB6 so you need to define your variable types: Dim adoCon As ADODB.Connection and Dim adoRS as ADODB.Recordset. For this to work you must set a reference to MIcrosoft ActiveX Data Objects via the VB6 Project->References menu.